# Can I delete dictionary entries in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, dictionary

You know how it is:  Red sqiggly line under word, looks OK to me, click on "Add to Dictionary" -- sudden realisation, that's NOT how you spell it. Now what?

Can I make things right again, or am I stuck with Word accepting a mis-spelling?

Answer (score 11):

Below are the steps to delete dictionary entries in Word 2007.

1. Open Word.
2. Click the Office button.
3. Click the Word Options button.
4. Click **Proofing** (Pic A - Step 1.)
5. Click **Custom Dictionaries** (Pic A - Step 2.)
6. Click **Edit Word List** (Pic A - Step 3.)
7. Select the word from the dictionary which you want to delete and click the **Delete** button. (Pic B)

[image: Word 2007 Options Screen]

**Pic A.**

[image: Dictionary Editor Screen]

**Pic B.**

Comment: Has anyone had the experience that they added a word accidentally, but it does not show in the custom dictionary? So it can't be removed? It is just *somewhere*.