# Spellchecker in Word 2007 refuses to remember a new word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, spell-check

> [image]

My MS Word 2007 refuses to put this "cytotoxicity" into its library and keeps highlighting it as wrong. It offers to change it to "cytotocixity" actually - I must have made a wrong input into its library earlier. Now I select the "add to the library command" in the menu called by pressing the right button of the mouse, but to no avail.

Comment: Try [removing the incorrect spellings of it from Word's dictionary](http://superuser.com/questions/58782/can-i-delete-dictionary-entries-in-word) and see if it starts working as expected...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - it worked, thank you!